# Skyrim:Papyrus Possible Conflict Error [18+?]

Tags: architecture, skyrim-modding, code-reflection

I am working with a friend of mine to create a mod that relies on a mod called Devious devices, which would allow BDSM be utilized in Skyrim's combat by allowing the assailants to have special weapons which, when power attacking, allow for the player to be slowly bound with different pre-selected devices which inhibit the player until they are completely bound and helpless. We are still stuck on phase one of getting the code itself to fire off before we work more fully on the aesthetics, but the .xml files does not work for some reason and we need help. We believe the code compiles correctly, but when the script is called on

```
        Armor toremove = akTarget.GetWornForm(0x00000001) as Armor
        akTarget.UnequipItem(toremove)
    EndIf
```

is the current block that has been singled out as possibly causing the issue as it has not fired correctly. **The main goal here is to have a function which unequips the item the target is currently wearing then replace it with another item provided. Right now we are working on the force unequip part.**

I am happy to give more information and we are using the mod Devious Devices with all prerequisite mods installed and utilized for the testing environment. Please help us help you help us find a way to have a kinkier skyrim

Comment: Can you tell us more about what's going wrong? Is there an error message, or a particular observable symptom? It looks like this code is the tail end of a conditional block - can you show us the whole block in context?